# Algebraic proof on the $0$ entries of the powers of a matrix with entries in $\{0,1\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, alternative-proof

In this question, a graph is a nonoriented, unlabeled, simple graph.

Such a graph can be represented by its incidence matrix $G$: if the vertices of the graph are labeled by $1,2,3,...,n$, then $G$ is the $n\times n$ matrix so that the entry $G[i,j]$ at row $i$ and column $j$ is equal to $1$ if there is an edge between vertices $i$ and $j$, and $0$ otherwise.

For $k\geqslant 1$, the entries of the powers $G^k$ of $G$ have a nice interpretation: $G^k[i,j]$ is the number of paths of length exactly $k$ from $i$ to $j$. Here, a path can go through a same vertex multiple times.

Assume that the graph has $n$ vertices. Then the minimum length of a path between two vertices is at most $n-1$. This leads to the following theorem:

> Let $G$ be a symmetric $n\times n$ matrix with entries in $\{0,1\}$. If $G^k[i,j]=0$ for $k\in\{1,2,\dots,n-1\}$, then $G^k[i,j]=0$ for every $n\geqslant 1$.

That's a nice proof, but I am wondering if there is a direct way to prove this, using linear algebra.

**How can we prove the theorem above using linear algebra?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prove the following more general statement:

**Lemma** Let $G$ be any symmetric $n \times n$ matrix. If $i,j$ is any entry such that $G^k[i,j]=0 \forall 1 \leq k \leq n-1$ then $G^n[i,j]=0 \forall n\geq 1$.

**Proof:**

Sketch of the proof.

*Case 1:* $i=j$, then, since $G$ is symmetric we have 
$$
0=G^2[i,i]=\sum_{k=1}^n G[i,k]^2 
$$

This shows that the $i$^th row of $G$ is identically $0$, from where, by induction you can prove that the $i$th row of $G^nb$ is zero for all $n \geq 1$.

*Case 2* $i \neq j$.

Let $P_G=X^n+a_{n-1}X^{n-1}+...+a_1X+a_0$ be the characteristic polynomial of $G$. Then, by hamilton -Cayley we have $P_G(G)=0$ and hence 
$$G^n=-a_{n-1}G^{n-1}-a_{n-1}G^{n-2}-...-a_1G-a_0I (*)$$

In particular, for each $ m \geq 0$ you have 
$$G^{n+m}=-a_{n-1}G^{n-1+m}-a_{n-1}G^{n-2+m}-...-a_1G^{1+m}-a_0G^m$$

From here, it follows immediately by induction of $m$ that for all $m \geq 0$ you have
$$G^{n+m}[i,j]=0$$

**Note** $G$ symmetric is only used to sort the case $i=j$. Alternately, you can drop this requirement and prove the following statement:

Let $G$ be any  $n \times n$ matrix. If $i,j$ is any entry such that $G^k[i,j]=0 \forall 1 \leq k \leq n$ then $G^m[i,j]=0 \forall m\geq 1$.

Note that for $i \neq j$, if you know that $G^k[i,j]=0 \forall 1 \leq k \leq n-1$, the equation (*) implies that this also holds for $k=n$.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding your claim, but for your note at the end, isn't $G=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$ a counterexample? $G^k[1,1]=0$ for all $k,$ but $G$ is nonzero.

Comment: @Stahl I think the claim is that $G^n[i,j]=0$ for all $n$

Comment: @Stahl That was a typo, fixed it. The claim is: if the (i,j) entry of $G^k$ is zero for all $1 \leq k \leq n$ then the $(i,j)$ entry of $G^m$ is zero for all powers of $G$. Not that $G^m$ is zero.